# Dynamic TableView in Javafx

Tags: java, sqlite, dynamic, javafx, tableview

i am trying to populate a tableview with data from a sqlite-db, but it is not really working. the bug must be somewhere in the "col.setCellValueFactory(...)".

i am not really into javafx, so it would be nice if you could help me out :)

thanks!

```
public class DynamicTable{

ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
@FXML TableView tableview;

public void buildData(String table, String filter){
    tableview=new TableView();
    String SQL=null;
    Connection c= DBController.getConnection();
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try{
        switch(table){
            case "Kuenstler":{
                SQL="SELECT * FROM Kuenstler";
                break;
            }
            case "Kunstwerke":{
                SQL="SELECT * FROM Kunstwerk WHERE Kunststil_Name='"+filter+"'";
                break;
            }
            case "Museen":{
                SQL="SELECT Museum.Name, Adresse.Stadt FROM Museum JOIN Gebaeude JOIN Adresse ON Museum.GebaeudeID=Gebaeude.GebaeudeID AND Adresse.AdressID=Gebaeude.AdressID WHERE Stadt='"+filter+"'";
                break;
            }
            case "Sammlungen":{
                SQL="SELECT * FROM Sammlung";
                break;
            }
        }


        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
        //Bug must be in this for-loop
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        while(rs.next()){

            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);

        }           
        tableview.setItems(data);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }

}
```

}

thats where i call the buildData:

```
    DynamicTable dTable;
    @FXML ChoiceBox filter_choice;
    @FXML TextField filter_filter;
    @FXML
    public void handleSearch(ActionEvent event){
        dTable=new DynamicTable();
        System.out.println(filter_choice.getValue());
        dTable.buildData((String)filter_choice.getValue(),filter_filter.getText());
    }
```

TableView:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableview" editable="false" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="309.0" prefWidth="558.0"/>
```

Scene change:

```
filterScene=new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("filter.fxml")),600,550);
mainStage.setScene(filterScene);
```

Comment: What does "it is not really working" mean? Does it compile? Do you get an exception? What happens?

Comment: its not throwing any exceptions, but the tableview is not changing. (the sql-part is fine)

Comment: intellij says "unchecked call to 'setCellValueFactory(...)'"

Comment: Well that's just because you are using raw types all over the place, which is (very) bad practice, but is not causing the issue. There's nothing logically wrong with the code you posted, so your errors are elsewhere. Where are you calling `buildData` from? Where do you add the new table to the scene graph? I don't think this has anything to do with the database, so [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] which can be executed without a database resource.

Comment: did some editing, thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Your code as it stands is not understandable: e.g. why is `tableview` annotated `@FXML` if you are creating an instance of `DynamicTable` yourself (i.e. is `DynamicTable` supposed to be a controller class? If so, why are you instantiating it: if not, why do you have `@FXML`-annotated fields in it)? Where is `tableview` added to the scene graph? Without enough context, no-one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the annotation `@FXML` you don't need any more to do `new TableView()` because all the properties are in your fxml file.